# Trying to access aggregates inside commands

Tags: wolkenkit

How can I obtain the state of another object, let's say `usermanagement.user` from inside a command or event of an object, let's say `administration.regulation`? Scenario: I have profiles inside regulations that contain simple sets of rules, and after the user has done something, I want to see if met the rules. I tried doing that inside the commands and actions inside the user, and I tried obtaining the regulation inside a flow, but I can't seem to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wolkenkit](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit) offers an option to access other aggregates from within an aggregate's command handler. This is done by using [services](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/2.0.0/reference/creating-the-write-model/using-command-services/#reading-other-aggregates).

E.g., a command handler usually looks like this:

```
const commands = {
  doSomething (file, command) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

Now, by using services, you can access the `app` object itself, as a client does. For that, use `services` as the third parameter to the command handler. Then, inside the command handler, you can use `services.app` to read other aggregates. Please note that you have to use the `await` keyword here:

```
const commands = {
  async doSomething (file, command, services) {
    // ...

    const otherAggregate = await services.app.someContext.someAggregate(id).read();

    // ...
  }
};
```

Optionally, you may use object destructuring and simplify the code slightly:

```
const commands = {
  async doSomething (file, command, { app }) {
    // ...

    const otherAggregate = await app.someContext.someAggregate(id).read();

    // ...
  }
};
```

You can find all the details on this in the [documentation](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/2.0.0/reference/creating-the-write-model/using-command-services/#reading-other-aggregates).

Hope this helps

Comment: I think it would help a lot if the API had something like a `readAll()` function, because I found that in some cases I needed all other aggregates of a specific type. Maybe it is more elegant to solve this another way, I am not quite sure.

Comment: This is pretty hard in the write model, as this means replaying every single aggregate. A read model is better for this, but then you have to take eventual consistency into account. It maybe would be best to reconsider the actual use case and think about this in a specific way, to be able to decide, what other options are there.